# Not able to use Confluent.Kafka.Serialization. Any other nuget library i should install?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, serialization

I am following a guide on youtube on creating a Consumer application for Kafka using C# but on the Using portion, I was not able to use Confluent.Kafka.Serialization.  Serialization is missing.

Any idea on what should I include/use to be able to use the StringDeserializer?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the tutorial you are following uses the old Confluent.Kafka library which is outdated.

If you want to set deserializer you can use [SetValueDeserializer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/f76a224c658b8f18c77b2719b508c78486a8265f/src/Confluent.Kafka/ConsumerBuilder.cs#L231) and [SetKeyDeserializer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/f76a224c658b8f18c77b2719b508c78486a8265f/src/Confluent.Kafka/ConsumerBuilder.cs#L212) methods which accept [IDeserializer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/IDeserializer.cs) interface. You can implement your own deserializer which could use StringDeserializer internally.

Also you can take a look at another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62774268/6827508) which provides a simple IDeserializer implementation.